# Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $f_n$ convergenc pointwise and that it doesn't converge uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, 0 \le x \le\frac{1}{2n} \\2n(x-\frac{1}{2n}), \frac{1}{2n}<x<\frac{1}{n} \\ 1, \frac{1}{n}\le x \le 1 \end{cases}$. Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise and that it doesn't converge uniformly.

When $0 \le x \le \frac{1}{2n}$ I have that $f_n(x)= 0$ so as constant it converges pointwise.

When $ \frac{1}{2n}<x<\frac{1}{n}$ I have that $f_n(x)=2n(x-\frac{1}{2n}) \le 2n(\frac1n-\frac{1}{2n})=2-1=1$ so $f_n$ converges pointwise?

Similarly for $\frac{1}{2n}<x<\frac{1}{n}$ $f_n =1$ is constant and converges pointwise.

How do approach the uniform convergence?

Comment: @Gary What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Overall, what $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence? Also after "Similarly for" you got the bounds for $x$ incorrectly.

Comment: It seems that for $x > 1$ the limit would be $1$ and for $x = 0$ we have $0$?

Comment: You mean for $x>0$?

Comment: Ok, now check that each $f_n$ is continuous. If the convergence was uniform, the limit function would be continuous too. Is the limit function continuous?

Answer (score 1):

$f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0, 0 \le x \le\frac{1}{2n} \\2n(x-\frac{1}{2n}), \frac{1}{2n}<x<\frac{1}{n} \\ 1, \frac{1}{n}\le x \le 1 \end{cases}$

First let's establish pointwise convergence on $(0,1]$:

Note that given any $x\in (0,1], \exists N\in \mathbb N:\frac 1N\lt x$

For any $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $x, \exists N: \frac 1 N\lt x$ and $n\gt N \implies |f_n (x)-1|=0\lt \epsilon\implies \lim f_n(x)=f(x)=1$

$f_n(x)\to f(x)=\begin{cases}0; x=0\\ 1; x\in (0,1] \end{cases}$

Suppose on the contrary that the convergence is uniform:

In particular for $\epsilon=\frac 12, \exists N_\epsilon:n\ge N_\epsilon$ and $0\lt x\lt \frac 1{2 N_\epsilon}$ should imply $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\lt \frac 12$ but clearly $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|0-1|=1\gt \frac 12$, which is a contradiction.

So the convergence $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ is pointwise and not uniform.

Comment: How is it true that for any $x \in (0, 1]$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac1N < x$?

Comment: @DanielLi: That is true by Archimedes property of real numbers.

Comment: @DanielLi: In more words, if no such N exists then for all n, we’ll have $n\le x$, which is a contradiction.